# SQL, Only the same selection

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have a table:

```
Music track    Name
==             ====
1              A 
2              A 
3              B 
3              C 
3              D 
4              C
5              E
5              F
6              E
6              F
..             ..
```

I want to select all the names who listen the **same and only the same music track**. The result should be:

```
Name
====
B (listens track 3 and only track 3)
D (listens track 3 and only track 3)
E (listens tracks 5, 6 and only tracks 5,6)
F (listens tracks 5,6 and only tracks 5,6)
..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, I would do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select tracks, group_concat(name) as names
from (select name, group_concat(track order by track) as tracks
      from t
      group by name
     ) n
group by tracks;
```

This lists every combination of tracks in the data and the users who are associated with exactly that list.

Comment: I think maybe because you gave them the info they wanted but not in the format they wanted it in.

Comment: although the description and the sample result set in the question doesn't match up either :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select tracks, group_concat(name) as group_concated_name 
from 
(
    select name, group_concat(track order by track) as tracks 
    from t 
    group by name 
) n1 
group by tracks;
```